# how to resolve the error Rscript not found error while submitting the job in HPC

Tags: r, hpc

I'm trying to run a R program `myscript.R` in HPC cluster. here's my script `job.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
#PBS -q vshort
#PBS -e error.e
#PBS -o error.o
#PBS -N R1
#PBS -V
cd /home/suryamukhi
Rscript myscript.R
```

and my `myscript.R` contains the code

```
print("hello world")
```

when I submit the job using `qsub job.sh` I get the error saying `Rscript not found`. I even tried `module load R`. but I got the error `module not found`. I'am unable to understand the error here.Here's some information about OS and R version.

```
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
arch           x86_64
os             linux-gnu
system         x86_64, linux-gnu
status
major          3
minor          2.3
year           2015
month          12
day            10
svn rev        69752
language       R
version.string R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
nickname       Wooden Christmas-Tree
```

I edited my `job.sh` file as shown below

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -l nodes=1:ppn=1
#PBS -q vshort
#PBS -e error.e
#PBS -o error.o
#PBS -N R1
#PBS -V
cd /home/suryamukhi
/opt/softwares/Rsoftware/R-3.2.3/bin/R <myscript.R
```

and now I'm getting the following error:

```
/opt/softwares/Rsoftware/R-3.2.3/bin/exec/R: error while loading shared libraries: liblzma.so.5: cannot open shared obj
ect file: No such file or directory
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what OS the cluster is working on?

Comment: @Roman Luštrik: I'am working on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6 (Tikanga)

Comment: Are you sure that R is installed on the worker node?  In the job.sh script, try running "R --version".

Comment: @Derek: I'am getting an error "R not found" if I run "R --version". But, R has been installed in Login node

Comment: @Derek: When I run R --version from bash, it works but it throws me error if I run from the script "job.sh"

Comment: @SuryamukhiKuchibhotla That seems to indicate that R is not installed on the worker nodes.  You will have to contact the system administrators.